# Adding source validation to a StructuredTextViewer

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I added to my application a nice XML source viewer. Now, I have an XSD scheme that defines the xml document. Any idea where to start on adding some source validation that relies on this scheme?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To check that your XML is well-formed, just run it through a DocumentBuilderFactory parser. To additionally validate it against an .xsd schema referenced in the XML, call:

```
factory.setValidating( true );
```

If the xsd schema is not referenced within the XML that you are validating, you can supply it yourself like this:

```
factory.setAttribute(JAXP_SCHEMA_SOURCE, new File(schemaSource) );
```

For more information, read the article from Oracle here:
http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPDOM8.html